# Extrude along normals, stuck going diagonally instead of inwards/outwards

Tags: modeling, extrude, scale

Folllowing a tutorial series and for the love of me can't get Blender to replicate what Alt+E > Region (Vertex Normals) does in their example.

1. Select all linked geometry
2. Alt+E > Region (Vertex Normals)

I negated this by using the thickness modifier to achieve the same results but given this is a tutorial series, *I wanted to learn things the way they're showing.*

[image]
In my Blender it extrudes diagonally only, can't get it to scale inwards like in the picture.
I've tried pressing x,y,z and middle mouse to possibly change the axis/way it is scaling.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Thanks.

Comment: You could try hitting E to extrude, then right-clicking to cancel the actual displacement. Then, use Alt + S to Shrink/Fatten, which moves each individual face along its individual normal.

Comment: @rekov just tried that and I get the same issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool is Extrude Region and Shrink/Fatten. 
Hit the Space bar and type the name, and move it a little bit (it's going to loock weird) and then select offset even on the tool shelf.

[image]

Good Luck

Comment: That's what I've been doing, guess there was an issue with how I set up the mesh or with blender. Restarted my PC, opened blender and remade the whole thing from scratch and I was able to get it. Weird. Thanks.